# Go Build Errors on GCP Shell -- Permission Denied to Local Go Build Packages?

Tags: shell, go, google-cloud-platform

**QUESTION: Are my persisted Google Cloud Platform Shell user configuration settings the root of the problem?  Or, does Google need to reinstall the Go binary installation on the machine used to provision users' virtual machine instances?**

#### BACKGROUND

When using the GCP Shell editor (Theia IDE) to work on Go source code, the following problem is identified:

```
go build runtime/internal/atomic: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/runtime/internal/atomic.a: permission denied
go build runtime/internal/sys: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/runtime/internal/sys.a: permission denied
go build internal/cpu: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/internal/cpu.a: permission denied
go build math/bits: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/math/bits.a: permission denied
go build internal/race: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/internal/race.a: permission denied
go build sync/atomic: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/sync/atomic.a: permission denied
go build unicode/utf8: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/unicode/utf8.a: permission denied
go build unicode: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/unicode.a: permission denied
go build crypto/internal/subtle: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/crypto/internal/subtle.a: permission denied
go build crypto/subtle: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/crypto/subtle.a: permission denied
go build internal/nettrace: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/internal/nettrace.a: permission denied
go build vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/cryptobyte/asn1: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/cryptobyte/asn1.a: permission denied
go build runtime/cgo: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/runtime/cgo.a: permission denied
```

If I deploy to GCP App Engine Standard, everything compiles and works fine.  Therefore, it seems like the challenge is limited to the local development environment on the provisioned virtual machine/terminal?

It sounds like this had been [a fairly common challenge](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fgo%2Fpkg+permission+denied), perhaps with an earlier compile or installation of the Go binary release install in general (i.e. beyond GCP Shell)?

I was able to solve the problem temporarily by uninstalling the existing Go binary installation then reinstalling, using the shell commands below.  However, because the GCP Shell is a virtual machine instance, the Go binary release install is re-provisioned whenever a shell instance is closed and another is started; the Go binary release install is outside my persistent disk storage mounted as the $HOME directory on the instance.

```
cd ~
wget "https://dl.google.com/go/go1.13.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz"  # get fresh Go binary installation release version
sudo rm --recursive /usr/local/go # uninstall the Sept 3 Go binary installation release version
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.13.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz  # install fresh Go binary installation release version
rm go1.13.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz  # remove downloaded Go binary install package
```

Other potentially useful information appears below:

**PATH:**

```
/home/lance_hegland/bin
/home/lance_hegland/gopath/bin
/google/gopath/bin
/usr/local/go/bin
/opt/gradle/bin
/opt/maven/bin
/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v10.14.2/bin
/google/go_appengine
/google/google_appengine
```

**Go Version**

```
* go1.13 linux/amd64 (original)
* go1.13.7 linux/amd64 (post-reinstall)
```

**Go Environmental Variables**

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/lance_hegland/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/lance_hegland/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/lance_hegland/gopath:/google/gopath"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build248154127=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: Looks suspiciously like https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27285

Comment: Hello, what exactly is done just before this error occurs? `go run .`? I have successfully deployed with `go run .` in the Cloud Shell a helloworld go app ( github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/appengine/go11x/helloworld ).

Comment: @asbovelw -- Oddly enough, I can't replicate error from command line at this time.  No idea what changed.  It `go build`s and `go run`s from command line, at this moment (i.e. without the workaround from my original post).

**_However_**, I'm still notified of same errors from my original post when I'm entering valid Go code in Cloud Shell editor (i.e. Theia IDE).  It looks like editor is attempting to validate code using `go build -i -o /tmp/go-code-check tut-go-hello`, where tut-go-hello is project name.  File being edited is `~/gopath/src/tut-go-hello/main.go`.

Comment: i recommend you to post this in [Issue Tracker](https://www.issuetracker.google.com) so the engineers can investigate this, as it seems a bug.

Comment: Thank you @asbovelw , as you suggested, I submitted [this potential issue to Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150025239).

Comment: you are welcome, @LanceHegland. i hope this gets resolved soon.